# Should I capitalize the first letter of an Italian sentence like in English language?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, capitalization

In English, the first letter of every sentence is capitalized. Do we do that too in Italian writing?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any language written in the Latin alphabet where the first word of a sentence is _not_ capitalised?

Comment: Yes, you should, but there is one notable difference with English: in Italian, you do *not* capitalize the first letter of the first line after a missive opening (unless the word is proper noun). In other words, in English you write "Dear John, [_new line_] **T**oday..." but in Italian you write "Caro John, [_new line_] **o**ggi..."

Comment: Un caso molto interessante qui sarebbe le frasi che iniziano con un mese. Esempio: "Luglio... " Nella lingua italiana (e tutte le lingue nel mondo), i mesi non seguono le regole tipiche.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, also in Italian it's mandatory to capitalize the first letter of each sentence, as you can see in this [article from Treccani encyclopedia](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uso-delle-maiuscole_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/):

> L'*uso delle maiuscole* è obbligatorio in una serie di casi. 
> • All’inizio di testo o di una sua parte (capitolo, paragrafo ecc.) 
> Quel ramo del lago di Como che volge a mezzogiorno (A. Manzoni, *I promessi sposi*) 
> • Dopo un punto fermo 
> Tornò a Roma. Laggiù si sentiva a casa 
> • All'inizio di una battuta di discorso diretto 
> Luigi disse: «Arrivo domani»